# equidivision partition using breadth first search

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

i was trying to solve a breadth first search problem on spoj.the problem statement is as follows:
An equidivision of an n × n square array of cells is a partition of the n^2 cells in the array in exactly n sets, each one with n contiguous cells. Two cells are contiguous when they have a common side.
the problem link is:http://www.spoj.com/problems/EQDIV/

my code:http://ideone.com/OjluJG

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
#define pii pair< int, int>
int n, m, grid[105][105];
char inp[101 * 101];

bool inRange(int i, int j)
{
    m = n;
    return (i >= 0 && i < n && j >= 0 && j < m);
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, comp;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            printf("good\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            continue;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        int a, b, start1[n], start2[n], print = 0, c, d;
        queue< pii > Q;
        pii p;
        getchar();
        for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
        {
            gets(inp);
            stringstream ss(inp);
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                ss >> a >> b;
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    start1[i - 1] = a;
                    start2[i - 1] = b;
                    //printf("%d %d\n",start1[i-1],start2[i-1]);
                }
                grid[a - 1][b - 1] = i;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            int count = 1;
            if (x == n - 1)
            {
                comp = 0;
                p.first = c;
                p.second = d;
                Q.push(p);
            }
            else
            {
                comp = x + 1;
                p.first = start1[x] - 1;
                p.second = start2[x] - 1;
                Q.push(p);
            }
            while (!Q.empty())
            {
                p = Q.front();
                i = p.first;
                j = p.second;
                Q.pop();
                grid[i][j] = -1;
                if (x != n - 1)
                {
                    if (inRange(i + 1, j) && grid[i + 1][j] == 0)
                    {
                        c = i + 1;
                        d = j;
                    }
                    if (inRange(i - 1, j) && grid[i - 1][j] == 0)
                    {
                        c = i - 1;
                        d = j;
                    }
                    if (inRange(i, j + 1) && grid[i][j + 1] == 0)
                    {
                        c = i;
                        d = j + 1;
                    }
                    if (inRange(i, j - 1) && grid[i][j - 1] == x + 1)
                    {
                        c = i;
                        d = j - 1;
                    }
                }

                if (inRange(i + 1, j) && grid[i + 1][j] == comp)
                {
                    p.first = i + 1;
                    p.second = j;
                    Q.push(p);
                    count += 1;
                }
                if (inRange(i - 1, j) && grid[i - 1][j] == comp)
                {
                    p.first = i - 1;
                    p.second = j;
                    Q.push(p);
                    count += 1;
                }
                if (inRange(i, j + 1) && grid[i][j + 1] == comp)
                {
                    p.first = i;
                    p.second = j + 1;
                    Q.push(p);
                    count += 1;
                }
                if (inRange(i, j - 1) && grid[i][j - 1] == comp)
                {
                    p.first = i;
                    p.second = j - 1;
                    Q.push(p);
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            if (count != n)
            {
                print = 1;
                printf("wrong\n");
                break;

            }
        }
        if (print == 0)
            printf("good\n");
        //printf("%d %d\n",c,d);
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
}
```

i am getting wrong answer ,don't know why?
can someone provide the testcase for which it is wrong?

Comment: Can you try to narrow it down? Have you tried debug it?

Comment: @LihO yeah i have and it is giving correct output for the given test cases.The approach is to apply bfs for every individual number in the grid and count its appearance as per the given condition in the question.